# Why does a variable and the value it points to both have the same address in Python 3.6.5?

Tags: python-3.x

Why are these the same address? Is it because the integer 4 is actually an Object in Python and therefore a variable which points to this same integer will have the memory address of this particular integer Object?

```
hex(id(4)) #will return '0x10b684900' 

x = 4

hex(id(x)) #will return '0x10b684900'
```

Answer (score 1):

In python everything is an object! Maybe this answer will help you understand!

[Python 3.6: Memory address of a value vs Memory address of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805113/python-3-6-memory-address-of-a-value-vs-memory-address-of-a-variable][1])

Answer (score 1):

Please read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/8733066

The python interpreter doesn't need tho save the value 4 multiple times because `int` is immutable. So all variables with the value four point to the same memory location.